# Web Browser Control prevent Are you sure you want to leave this page

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have an application which is used to navigate to another page, a Kind of web browser, The problem is for some web pages it says "Are you sure you want to leave this page ? " dialogue. I want to remove it totally. It should start navigating without this dialogue. I  tried this,

```
WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

Screenhot : http://image.prntscr.com/image/5d1adcbd60794f22b5ad7baf736b29f2.png

I have also tried to disable javascript but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What application? I'm pretty sure that the dialog is not a "scripterror", therfor this setting won't help you.

Comment: The application is to increase my blog post's view. Because of this it stops.

Comment: Well, an example would be if you open the facebook and you write some message and then try to refresh browser it will show this message. Try it in internet explorer. This was just an example, there are lots of other websites which stops you to navigate without this popup. I have added the screenshot. Kindly check it out.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = null;` is your friend probably as it is JavaScript...

Comment: @kayess : Thanks mate! This is the correct answer. I have injected this javascript and worked like a charm. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript [onbeforeunload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp) event is responsible to handle such messages. By setting it to `null` as:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

you can prevent its handlers code from running.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
Dim head As HtmlElement = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
Dim s As HtmlElement = doc.CreateElement("script")
s.SetAttribute("text", "function cancelOut() { window.onbeforeunload = null; }")
head.AppendChild(s)
WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("cancelOut")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the unsafe native methods which can be found [here](https://github.com/Yonom/MetroWeb/blob/master/MetroWeb/WebBrowser/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs) to intercept the new window event(s)